# Performance impact for specifying qualitative temporal information in Django signals?

Tags: django, performance, signals

When defining a Signal in Django, should you specify qualitative temporal information such as *pre* and *post* in the name of the Signal, or as an argument? If as an argument, what range of values should you use?

For instance, say I want to define Signals before and after an operation X, one way is:

```
pre_x_signal = Signal(providing_args = ['foo', ])

post_x_signal = Signal(providing_args = ['foo', ])
```

and the alternative is:

```
x_signal = Signal(providing_args = ['foo', 'stage', ])
```

where `stage` takes values in some range, e.g. `['pre', 'post', ]`

Depending on the choice, different lookup logic will be followed both by Django and by your code, so how will this impact performance?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you haven't had an answer to this for a full week, I'd suggest you're probably not going to get a definitive one any time soon.

So, like all performance issues, I'd recommend contriving a test and doing an experiment!  The theoretical performance of any system is always going to differ from the observable fact.  Write a test comparing the two approaches you're interested in and try it!  Even better, post the results here (or to some Django-users list?) so that you can forever provide a reasonable answer to this question.